# Using Stacked Labels with $length and single quote in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-2.18, labeling

I am using QGIS and making stacked labels.

Using $length, how do I get a ' (single quote) to show up after the length ie 386'?

My current expression is:

```
run  +  '\n'  +  "sequence"   ||  '\n'  ||  round($length,0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your field is named "sequence", then a simple solution to just add a single quote after a number field would be with the `concat()` function:

```
concat( "sequence", '''')
```

Result:

[image]

With the rest of your formulas (might need some adjustment) it should look something like this:

```
concat( run , '\n' , "sequence" , '\n' , round($length,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the following will help you out:
Go to labels -> placement -> repeat - punch in your number and set your choice of map units of milimeters.

Sorry for the german menu, couldn't switch to english right now: [image]

Comment: I cannot get these to work with "round($length,0)" The bottom number is where I need the ' or foot indicator. Otherwise I am happy. Thanks

Comment: Oh, sorry, I am not used to imperial units, therefore I didn't see the foot-symbol. If you put the following expression in the field "label with": round($length,0) || ' ´' or concat(round($length,0),' ´')

Comment: Thanks for your help, I still could not get the ' to work, so decided to go to lf for linear feet, I notice your middle ' is angled, is that a different symbol from the single quote?

Comment: OK I got it to work bu using a ʼ from character map, Thank You for your guidance